# how can I give FTP files link for make them downloadable easily through that link?

Tags: server, ftp, symbolic-link, hard-link

I am new here and a beginner at Linux Ubuntu. First of all, I created an FTP server and configured it. I give access only to some users that I choose.  When I try to download files through get command, It works fine. Here is my problem. Can I give these files a link so that remote users will be able to access and download it through that link?  I heard Symbolic link.  Does it solve my problem or should I  look for something else for my purpose. Also, Can I make the link limited times. Like we are transferring files via wetransfer platform. If so, how? Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: If your goal is to have a semi-modern way of sharing files with people, perhaps even with password authentication, then FTP may not be the right tool for you. Consider going with [something like NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com). You can think of it like a "self-hosted Dropbox", though it's more than that.

Comment: Actually I know it is not safe; however, I need to do it in this way for my project so I do not have choice